# Is it possible to persist and then forward WCF messages to destination services?

Tags: wcf, routes

The goal I'm working toward is having a WCF routing service that can receive messages from clients, persist them to some type of data store, and then process/send them to their destination WCF services.

Things to consider:

- You can create a routing service by using the [ClientViaBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientviabehavior.aspx) (outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546553.aspx))
- The ClientViaBehavior will not work with basicHttpBinding, so I need to use wsHttpBinding (basicHttpBinding doesn't set the "To" header on the message, found out the hard way)
- The WCF Message object itself is sent to the Routing Service, where it can be persisted as a serialized string
- I don't want the Routing Service to know what's in the message - consequently, the service will not have a reference to the Data Contracts involved
- When the time comes to route the Message to its destination, I need to be able to create a channel between the Routing Service and the Destination Service
- It is not desirable for the Routing Service to be aware of each destination service - ideally, WCF could create the proper channel dynamically based on the content/headers of the message being processed.

Is this too much to ask of WCF? (I have a feeling it might be...)

Any advice on how to accomplish something like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 4 (or can move to it), WCF 4.0 has introduced a RoutingService infrastructure of its own.

Check it out, before you re-invent the wheel!

See [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for a great general intro to the new features (including RoutingService) in WCF 4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make your routing service accepts any message.

This link should help you: [Building a WCF Router, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx)